# Android Bottom Nav Bar Show After login in webview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, webview, android-webview

I'm working in android studio with single Main activity Which have Webview, I've added Bottom navigation bar in it and webview have login functionality, i want Bottom navigation bar not show in login it's shows after login How can i achieve this? i have only single main activity.

I'm trying to solve but I can't...

Main Activity Code:

```
myview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
progressBar=(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.prg);
WebSettings webSettings = myview.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app/");
bottomNavigationView= (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation1);
bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
// bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.webView).setVisible(false);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.action_profile:
            myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app/profilo.php");
            return;

        case R.id.action_order:
            myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app/ordini.php");
            return;

        case R.id.action_points:
            myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app/punti.php");
            return;

        case R.id.action_network:
            myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app/viparea.php");
            return;

        case R.id.action_home:
            myview.loadUrl("https://mysuite.app");
            return;

        default:
        return;

        }
    }
}
```

xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white1"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
```

Comment: Ok Now You have any knowledge about mine question??

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a LoginActivity that implements only the `WebView` and the MainActivity to contain the `BottomNavigationView`

Or if its essential that you use just one activity, you could employ the use fragments... We will create a new fragment called `loginFragment` and when inflating the `loginFragment`, we will replace the root layout instead of the child view, and set the `BottomNavigationView` visibility to invisible.

like so...

```
<!-- Take notice of the id assigned to the CoordinatorLayout -->
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Views.Discipleship.Supervisor.Main.MainActivityBottomNav">

<!-- Appabar / toolbar layout -->
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:background="#FFF">
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!-- Where you would normally replace your fragment layout -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<!-- Bottom navigation -->
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And in your MainActivity... when inflating your fragment,

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.rootLayout, fragment);
    transaction.commit();
```

Also as you have already done in your code above, remember to set the visibility of the `BottomNavigationView` back to visible when you load your next fragment.

Edit
[Creating a new fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaOcT.png)

Afterwards, in the window that opens, name your fragment, in our case, (LoginFragment)... Android will generate most of the code for you, including creating a layout file for the newly created fragment...

Create the `WebView` within that fragments layout file `fragment_login.xml` instead of the main activity layout, where it is now...

Now modify your main activity layout look like the xml above, afterwards inflate your LoginFragment using the codes above...

I suggest you read up on fragments to better understand whats going on here, especially the codes that will be generated for you in your new fragment...

Also I must state that all this is not conventional but it works... But then again, a WebView for login is not conventional either.

Comment: sir can you tell me more in detail??i'm new in android?? You said now i'm create an login fragment then what code i'm add in this fragment kindly tell me in detail?

Comment: Sir is it possible that bottom navbar show at specific url in one activity? Means To say that if i'm add an url that's open after login and bottom navbar open at this point??

Comment: Alright but could you please explain to me what exactly you are trying to achieve with the constant swapping out the bottom navbar... What are you trying to build?

Comment: Sir i'm doing work in project which have webview url,the client want that bottom nav bar showing after login,issue is this i'm doing work in only one activity ,and login is in url means to say that i'm not add login functionality it's already build in url ,the client require that it's show after login ,that's why i'm ask you it's possible that bottom nav bar show in specific url?